# required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I debug my webpage in the facebook linter, it keeps showing the warning:

"required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided"

I have read the suggestions on SO and have tried:

- no gzip compression
- re scrape on the fb debugger
- building new test page with only Facebook og meta tags

but the warning is the same.

The test page code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" >
<head>
   <title>testing page</title>
     <meta property="og:title" content="testing page og title" />  
     <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
     <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.skinvac.com/test.html" />
     <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.skinvac.com/test-image.png" />
     <meta property="og:description" content="testing page og description " />

      <meta name= "keywords" content="test " />
      <meta name= "description" content="test" />
</head>
    <body>
      <h1>test</h1>     
      <img src="test-image.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

The debug results can be seen here [facebook share debugger result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fskinvac.com%2Ftest.html)

There is a warning of: "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

But the "og:title" property is in the header tags.

How can I fix this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You are using https, but you do not have a valid SSL certificate. Replace https with http in your code and test with the http link instead.

Comment: thanks!!  you solved the problem, was up all night trying all the solutions in other answers, yours is the only one that works.  I get a warning on the linter that says: "The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. "  But the correct image is showing, should I ignore this warning?

Comment: i guess you can ignore it if it shows up, but you should consider using the correct image size/ratio: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images